# Is there any way to get project-id in google cloud endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I just want my project-id in the endpoint. Is there any way to get directly or I have to open app.yaml in endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using

```
APP_ID = str(os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID'))
APP_VERSION = float(os.getenv('CURRENT_VERSION_ID'))
APP_VERSION = int(APP_VERSION)
```